# Is there a way i can position Snackbar inside @ngmodule?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular12

I'm using snackbar in multiple components so i decided to set duration in main module and i want to add position as top

Here is my **app.module.ts**

```
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarVerticalPosition, MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
.
.

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {duration: 1500}}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

 }
```

Edit:
The snackbar method is same in another component.When i add it to the component method it shows an error:
Argument of type '{ verticalPosition: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Same happened when i added duration.

**CommodityComponent**

```
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition, MatSnackBarVerticalPosition } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';


@Component({})
export class CommodityListComponent implements OnInit {

 displayedColumns: string[] = [''];
 
 verticalPosition: MatSnackBarVerticalPosition = 'top';

 constructor(public svc: CommodityServiceService, private dialog: MatDialog,private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }
   getList() {
     this.svc.getCommodities();
   }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.getList();
 }
 Edit(e:any) {
  this.svc.Edit(e);
  const conf = new MatDialogConfig();
  conf.width = "30%";
  this.dialog.open(CommodityComponent, conf);
}
 openDialog() {
  this.svc.form.reset();
  const conf = new MatDialogConfig();
  conf.width = "30%";
  this.dialog.open(CommodityComponent, conf)
}
DeleteCommodity(e: any){
  debugger
  this.svc.DeleteRecord(e).subscribe(e => {
    this.openSnackBar("Record Deleted");
    this.svc.getCommodities();
  });
}
openSnackBar(message: string) {
  this._snackBar.open(message);
  
}
}
```

I'm using angular 12.0.1

Comment: What did you try? What's not working?

Comment: You could create a custom component wrapper/service (I don't remember how snackbar works) that contains the snackbar options and always use it rather than the original one.

Comment: i added position to my opensnackbar method but its showing ` Argument of type '{ this: any; top: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. `

Comment: Edit your question and show us your code

Comment: same happened when when i added duration to this method, so i added duration inside ngModule

Comment: If needed, there are some good examples on the official documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/examples

Comment: Fixed it, added action to the method and then it stopped showing error for position and duration

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have not added action string to my openSnackbar method it looked something like this:

```
openSnackBar(message: string) {
  this._snackBar.open(message,{
    verticalPosition:this.verticalPosition
  }
 );  
}
```

i think it was expexting action that's why it was showing me an error.So, i added `action: string` parameter and passed `""` as an argument and my method looked something like this:

```
openSnackBar(message: string,Action:string) {
  this._snackBar.open(message,Action,{
    verticalPosition:this.verticalPosition
  }
  );
}
```

and it works!